# Client side API google.script.run not working

Tags: google-apps-script, callback

I am trying to get the div elements to be dynamically created and their values updated every second using the code:

```
setInterval(function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccesshandler(function(data) {
            var out = '';
            $(data).each(function() {
                out += "<p>" + $(this).val() + "</p>";
            });

            $('#item1').html(out);
        }).getReadyLine();
        }, 1000);

<div class="col-sm-3 col1">
                <h1 id="readyLine">Ready Line, <?= getCountReadyLine() ?> items</h1>
                <div class="item1" id="item1">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Code.gs code:

```
 function getReadyLine() {
  var rawData = sheetMAT.getRange(3, 2, sheetMAT.getLastRow() - 2, 5).getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<rawData.length; i++) {
    if (rawData[i][3] === "A Ready Line" && rawData[i][4] === "ATY") {
      temp1 = ' ' + data[i][0];
      temp2.push(data[i][1], temp1);
      dataReadyLine.push(temp2);
      temp1 = '';
      temp2 = [];
    }
  }
  return dataReadyLine;
}
```

But it is giving the following error in the Console:

VM4084 userCodeAppPanel:67 Uncaught TypeError: google.script.run.withSuccesshandler is not a function
    at VM4084 userCodeAppPanel:67
(anonymous) @ VM4084 userCodeAppPanel:67

Why is it not recognized as a function? Is there any mistake in the code i am missing?

Comment: now I changed code only to run (but it's still not working): google.script.run.withSuccesshandler(function(data) {
            document.getElementById("#item1").innerHTML = data;
            }).getReadyLine();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct [syntax is](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()
```

Please note 'H' in Handler is capital

Comment: Thank you Jack. Indeed correct, i noticed it later on :-).